# CSS grid showing label and input in 2 rows in mobile view

Tags: html, css

I want to create this div contents in the mobile view into a grid/flex so that the label of the email address is on a row and the other div which contains the input under it. i am really confused with the css. what is wrong here?

```css
.form-row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    grid-auto-rows: 30px, auto;
    padding: 12px 0 0 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="form-row"><label>Email address</label><div style="width: 100%;"><input type="email" name="email"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you just want to put the input box under the email address label?
if so then this should do it

```css
    .form-row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    grid-auto-rows: 30px, auto;
    padding: 12px 0 0 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="form-row"><label>Email address</label></div>
<div style="width: 100%;"> <input type="email" name="email"></div>
```

Comment: or do you want it so when a user opens the website on a phone the input box is under the email address label.And when they open it on a pc it is all in 1 row?

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line in your css

`grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;` to `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;`

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries

just try to change the screen size to notice changes

```css
.form-row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    grid-auto-rows: 30px, auto;
    padding: 12px 0 0 0;
 }
 
                 /*screen size*/
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .form-row {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row"><label>Email address</label><div style="width: 100%;"><input type="email" name="email"></div></div>
```